# RegExp parentheses not capturing

Tags: javascript, regex

I started messing with javascript a little and have a problem with regular expressions.
I have a string...

```
var example = "top:50px;right:50px;bottom:50px;left:50px;"
```

I want to extract the '50px' part from the string. 
I tried it with this code...

```
var theMatch = example.match(new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]+:([0-9]+px);'));
```

which extracts the 50px portion but only for the first occurence of the searched value in the string. I tried the 'g' modifier, but he is not capturing the 50px part. With the 'g' modifier, the result is na array with the entire match...

```
top:50px
right:50px
... etc ...
```

Is there a one line solution for this or i have to do another reg match? Also, are there any strange behaviour that involves the modifiers and the parenthesis that I am not aware of?

Comment: Do you want to get an array like `["50px","50px","50px","50px"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iteratively reapply the regex:

```
var myregexp = /[a-zA-Z]+:([0-9]+px);/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        // matched text: match[i], so match[1] contains e.g. "50px" 
    }
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

Comment: So, there is no php-like $mathes array that contains all the values matched within the parenthesis?

Comment: @MarioLegenda: I don't think so (and neither does [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works for values that does not contain `:` and `;` :

```
var s = 'top:50px;right:50px;bottom:50px;left:50px;';
s.match(/[^:;]+(?=;|$)/g);
```

The following one is based on keys :

```
var s = 'top:50px;right:50px;bottom:50px;left:50px;';
s.replace(/[ ;]+$/, '').split(/(?:^| *;).*?: */).slice(1);
```

Comment: Of course, this regex doesn't assert that there is an identifier/colon before the match. That might or might not matter to the OP.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the first sentence of your comment, could you rephrase?

Comment: I meant that the regex would also find `"50px"` even if it's not in context like `"top:50px"`.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Your regex matches the string `"50px"`, the OP's regex doesn't. In fact, your regex also matches `"lalala"`...

Comment: I guess you wanted to say "mine doesn't while OP's one does"? If I'm right, does the following one fit with your point of view : `/\d+px(?= *;| *$)/g`?

Comment: No, I meant what I said. Your new regex still matches the string `"50 px"`. As before, OP might or might not care that it does. His regex does *not* match this string, though.

Comment: I'm lost... `\d+px` does not match `"50 px"`... Anyway, although I care about understanding my mistake, I don't want you to waste your time with it :)